All tethering options greyed out, why?
On my Samsung Galaxy A-24, when I open in Settings Mobile Hotspot and Tethering section, all options are grayed out, such as Mobile Hotspot , Bluetooth tethering, USB  tethering, etc. The phone has a working mobile  data conection (at this moment turned on) and is connected  to the laptop via a  USB-C cable (with  scrcpy working over USB.).What can I do to share my data connection to the laptop? Maybe it depends on the mobile data  provider?

OP's previous question: Mobile Hotspot toggle is disabled / greyed out. How to share phone's data connection to laptop over WiFi?
